# Expand environment variables in text

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a function to perform substitutions of environment variables in java.  So if I had a string that looked like this:

> User ${USERNAME}'s APPDATA path is
>   ${APPDATA}.

I want the result to be:

> User msmith's APPDATA path is
>   C:\Users\msmith\AppData\Roaming.

So far my broken implementation looks like this:

```
public static String expandEnvVars(String text) {        
    Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();
    String pattern = "\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\}";
    Pattern expr = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = expr.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String envValue = envMap.get(matcher.group(i).toUpperCase());
            if (envValue == null) {
                envValue = "";
            } else {
                envValue = envValue.replace("\\", "\\\\");
            }
            Pattern subexpr = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{" + matcher.group(i) + "\\}");
            text = subexpr.matcher(text).replaceAll(envValue);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Using the above sample text, `matcher.matches()` returns false.  However if my sample text, is `${APPDATA}` it works.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't want to use [`matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()).  Matches will try to match the entire input string.

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

What you want is `while(matcher.find()) {`.  That will match each instance of your pattern.  Check out the documentation for [`find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

Within each match, `group 0` will be the entire matched string (`${appdata}`) and `group 1` will be the `appdata` part.

Your end result should look something like:

```
String pattern = "\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\}";
Pattern expr = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = expr.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String envValue = envMap.get(matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
    if (envValue == null) {
        envValue = "";
    } else {
        envValue = envValue.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    }
    Pattern subexpr = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(matcher.group(0)));
    text = subexpr.matcher(text).replaceAll(envValue);
}
```

Comment: Your example with matcher.group(0) throws because the ${} parts of the returned string must be escaped for this case.  So I used "\\$\\{" + matcher.group(1) + "\\}" for expression instead.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for pointing that out.  See my edit to get that to work. (hint, `Pattern.quote()`)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to write the code for yourself, the Apache Commons Lang library has a class called [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html). It does exactly this.

Comment: IMO, this is the cleanest solution. Implementation examples at https://dkbalachandar.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/how-to-use-strsubstitutor/. Or, if that link doesn't work, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770380/interpolating-environment-variables-in-string.

Answer (score 5):

The following alternative has the desired effect without resorting to a library:

- reads the map of environment variables once at startup
- on calling `expandEnvVars()` takes the text with potential placeholders as an argument
- the method then goes through the map of environment variables, one entry at at time, fetches the entry's key and value
- and tries to replace any occurrence of `${<key>}` in the text with `<value>`, thereby expanding the placeholders to their current values in the environment

```java
    private static Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();        
    public static String expandEnvVars(String text) {        
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : envMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            text = text.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + key + "\\}", value);
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: +1. This one is more compact than a library. When working under windows with paths I prefer `String value = entry.getValue().replace('\\', '/');` because otherwhise the "\" char is interpreted as escape which results in an invalid paths

Comment: While the accepted solution works, this one is more efficient since it doesn't need to use regular expressions.

Comment: @Dave C String # replaceAll uses regular expressions under the hood

Comment: In the future, please _explain_ the solution instead of just dumping a code block.

Comment: Depending on the number of set environment variables, this solution may be a lot less efficient than the accepted solution, because it scans the text for each set environment variable separately. The accepted solution scans the text once.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer but without nested pattern replacement.
Supports also default value and underscores in env-name: `${env-var[:default]}`

```
  static String substituteEnvVars(String text) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String pattern = "\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?::([^\\}]*))?\\}";
        Pattern expr = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = expr.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String varname = matcher.group(1);
            String envValue = System.getenv(varname);
            if (envValue == null) {
                envValue = matcher.group(2);
                if (envValue == null)
                    envValue = "";
            }
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, envValue);
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

In additon variables are exactly substituted once. Text "${VAR}${X}" with VAR=${X} and X=x  will be return "${X}x" not "xx".

Comment: @Gray, (?:X) is a non-capturing group, your change wasn't code fix. Found it already in java 1.5 docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Sorry @lexx9999.  I've been using regex for a decade now and didn't know that.  I also tested your code and thought it didn't work but it does now for me.  Sigh.  Rolled back.

Comment: @lexx9999, I'm naïeve; is that `:default` syntax from somewhere or did you make it up?

Answer (score 3):

I've taken @lexx9999 code and tweaked it a bit to use a `StringBuilder` and handle a Map as well as environmental variables.

```
private final static Pattern ENV_VAR_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9_.-]+)(?::([^\\}]*))?\\}");
/**
 * Handle "hello ${var}", "${var:default}" formats for environ variable expansion.
 */
public static String substituteEnvVars(String text) {
    return substituteEnvVars(text, System.getenv());
}
/**
 * Handle "hello ${var}", "${var:default}", find var in replaceMap replace value.
 */
public static String substituteEnvVars(String text, Map<String, ?> replaceMap) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = ENV_VAR_PATTERN.matcher(text);
    int index = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sb.append(text, index, matcher.start());
        String var = matcher.group(1);
        Object obj = replaceMap.get(var);
        String value;
        if (obj != null)
            value = String.valueOf(obj);
        else {
            // if no env variable, see if a default value was specified
            value = matcher.group(2);
            if (value == null)
                value = "";
        }
        sb.append(value);
        index = matcher.end();
    }
    sb.append(text, index, text.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're just trying to learn how to build things from scratch, you should not really bother implementing your own template engine - there are [multitudes already available](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines).

One very good one is [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) (which has [Java API](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/index.html)). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.bredelet.com/Denis/FreeMarker%20first%20steps.html).

Comment: I just found Apache commons org.apache.commons.exec.util.StringUtils.stringSubstitution(), it does exactly what I want, and we're already using exec.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for Windows is JNA's [`Kernel32Util.expandEnvironmentStrings()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/index.html?com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32Util.html) which calls the win32 function [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-expandenvironmentstringsforusera).

Quoting:

> Expands environment-variable strings and replaces them with the values defined for the current user.

Note, variables are escaped by `%` (percent) signs, not `$` (dollar) signs.

Example (after adding JNA to your project):

```java
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util;

...

String desktop = Kernel32Util.expandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop");
```

Warning: This solution uses the underlying win32 API, so it will only work for Windows platforms.