# new File() with environment variables in Java

Tags: java, file, environment-variables

How to get a File java object from its path string with environments vars?
For example:

```
new File("%SYSTEM_ROOT%/file.txt")
```

or

```
new File("${SYSTEM_ROOT}/file.txt")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the OP be using System.getenv?

Comment: I would like to know if exists a way to use enviroments variables in Files without replacing it manually!

Comment: @fge: `System.getProperty()` won't return an environment variable value.

Comment: @JBNizet Oops, yep, I mixed with `.getenv()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this Question is a little bit old, but no Answer yet.

In another Question about environment variables there is a simliar Problem and they have a sample code for regex:
[System Variable Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752940/2072528)

This code replaces all system vars that are in the format ${ENV_VAR}.

Hope that helps,
Kalasch

Answer (score 2):

Syntax that allows getting value of environment variable using `%` sign is a feature of windows shell. In java you should use `System.getenv("SYSTEM_ROOT")` instead, so your line should look like: `new File(System.getenv("SYSTEM_ROOT") + "/file.txt")` or even better `new File(new File(System.getenv("SYSTEM_ROOT"), "file.txt")`

Comment: Ok, the trouble is that the path is stored in a DB VAR, so i have this String "%SYSTEM_ROOT%/file.txt" (or "${SYSTEM_ROOT}/file.txt") and i need the relative object... however I understand there is no way, I may provide a regex replacement.