# Can File handle environment variables?

Tags: java, file, environment-variables

I have the following code in Java:

```
String path = "$ENV_PATH";
final File f = new File(path);
System.out.println(path);
if (f.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("A dir");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a dir");
}
```

If the environment variable is set and points to an actual directory, I get the following output:

```
$ENV_PATH
/actual/path/of/the/env/: Permission denied
Not a dir
```

Does `File` know how to handle environment variables? If not, what is a good alternative for that or how should I handle it? Please note that `path` can be non-env string. Also I would like to support paths like `/some/valid/path/$SUB/to/dir`.

**EDIT**: I understand that `File` does not support envs. What is the proper way to fix it?

Comment: No it can't. If it could its Javadoc would say so. In general you should not use environment variables in Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: So how should I solve it? I can check if it contains `$` in the path and then do `getenv` but it feels ugly because I will have to check the full string (to support `/some/path/$SUB1/and/$SUB2/`) Is there a proper way for that?

Answer (score 0):

> So how should I solve it? I can check if it contains `$` in the path and then do `getenv` but it feels ugly because I will have to check the full string (to support `/some/path/$SUB1/and/$SUB2/`) Is there a proper way for that?

There is no "proper" way to do this.  Basically `/some/path/$SUB1/and/$SUB2/` is "shell" syntax and Java does not support it.

I can think of three ways to do this:

1. Get a shell to deal with is; e.g. run `sh -c "echo /some/path/$SUB1/and/$SUB2/"` in a subshell and capture the output.  (This is very inefficient, but this approach also allows you to so shell wild-card expansion, interpolate the output of shell commands and so on.)
2. Write a simple parser that understands the syntax that you are using, and use it to *interpolate* the environment variables (or properties or whatever) into the string.

   Some of the answers to [Expand environment variables in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752817/expand-environment-variables-in-text) take this approach.
3. Look for a third party Java library that does what you want.  One possibility is the `StrSubstitutor` class in the Apache Commons library:  [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html)